# Migrate Magento Database to Another Server

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I am trying to migrate our Magento database to another server. Here is what I have done

1. Cloned the current VPS server to another VPS
2. Turned off httpd in the new server that I want to be the dbserver
3. Logged into mysql in the dbserver as root
4. GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'webserver_IP_address' IDENTIFIED BY
   'password';
5. From the webserver I was able to login to Mysql in the dbserver
   passing the IP address of the dbserver as the hostname
6. Renamed local.xml and tried to re-run Magento install wizard but
   could not get passed the DB connection screen.

I am providing the exact username, the exact password, the only thing that change is the hostname which I am entering the IP address of the dbserver instead of localhost

How can I point Magento to use a different remote db other than localhost

Comment: If you can SSH get access via CLI, are you able to connect to the DB server via the command line `mysql` ? Also double check firewall/iptables settings. Also be sure to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: Yes, I was able to ssh and connected via mysql command line. Reading up on what to check for the firewall/iptables as regards mysql

Comment: If you are able to connect via SSH from the web head, double check `etc/local.xml`, and manually wipe `var/cache` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a typo when I granted permission, a new database was created. I re-granted  permission for the correct Database and it went through.